# Questions regarding action at a distance

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, causality, locality, non-locality

There seems to be two concepts in [action at a distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance#:%7E:text=Newton%20considered%20this%20action%20at,other%20matter%20without%20mutual%20Contact%E2%80%A6)

1. The existence of an mediating medium (energy or matter) through which action is transmitted
2. The finiteness of the speed at which the action is transmitted.

Does 1. necessarily imply 2. or vice versa by some general principle?

Particularly, I am wondering about Section *Newtonian gravitation* where Newton was contemplating about the medium through which gravity would transmit. He thought there ought to be a medium, but did not say anything about the speed of propagation.

Comment: energy is not considered a medium, in my books

Comment: @annav: I am thinking about a photon which is an electromagnetic field or energy that transmit a wave or information or interaction.

Comment: The photon is an elementary particle in main stream physics, a large number of photons do build up a classical electromagnetic wave, in a complicated way, and electromagnetic waves do have fields and can carry information. I think that the questions are not clearly defined.

Comment: @annav: A photon is an all-permeating electromagnetic wave itself in quantum (electrodynamic) field theory. I edited the question a bit. Hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: Not correct. The **probability** distribution of a photon location, as of all other quantum particles, has a wave like behavior which is mathematically modeled in QED. Probabilities need accumulation of distributions to be observable .

Comment: @annav: Which part of my statement is not correct? I said the wave function of a photon is, e.g. $e^{i\omega(t-\frac zc)}$.